Parsing a section of output from a Cisco IOSXE show license all command with TextFSM
Im trying to parse out sections of the Cisco show license all command.  Some sections are more important than others so I've been trying to focus on those.  Perhaps a bad strategy.
In the output of Ciscos show license all command is a "Purchased Licenses" section, some of the time.  This is highly variable depending on model and code version (so its difficult to require anything).  Sometimes there won't be a purchased licenses section and if it is there it may not have the patterns I've shown below.
Within that "Purchased Licenses" section, I need to capture multiple nestings, if they exist.
At a minimum, I' looking for the Description (Filldown maybe?) and then Active: Standby: License Type: Start and End Date.
Example 1:
Purchased Licenses:
  C9500 48Y4C DNA Advantage (C9500 48Y4C DNA Advantage):
    Description: C9500 48Y4C DNA Advantage
    Total reserved count: 1
    Term information:
      Active: PID:C9500-48Y4C,SN:AB123456CDE
        License type: TERM
          Start Date: 2021-MAR-11 UTC
          End Date: 2026-MAR-11 UTC
          Term Count: 1
  C9500 Network Advantage (C9500 Network Advantage):
    Description: C9500 Network Advantage
    Total reserved count: 1
    Term information:
      Active: PID:C9500-48Y4C,SN:AB123456CDE
        License type: PERPETUAL
          Term Count: 1
 
 Example 2:
 Purchased Licenses:
  C9500 Network Advantage (C9500 Network Advantage):
    Description: C9500 Network Advantage
    Total reserved count: 2
    Term information:
      Active: PID:C9500-24Y4C,SN:AB123456CDE
        License type: PERPETUAL
          Term Count: 1
      Standby: PID:C9500-24Y4C,SN:AB123456CDE
        License type: PERPETUAL
          Term Count: 1
  C9500 24Y4C DNA Advantage (C9500 24Y4C DNA Advantage):
    Description: C9500 24Y4C DNA Advantage
    Total reserved count: 2
    Term information:
      Active: PID:C9500-24Y4C,SN:AB123456CDE
        License type: TERM
          Start Date: 2021-JUN-12 UTC
          End Date: 2026-JUN-12 UTC
          Term Count: 1
      Standby: PID:C9500-24Y4C,SN:AB123456CDE
        License type: TERM
          Start Date: 2021-JUN-12 UTC
          End Date: 2026-JUN-12 UTC
          Term Count: 1

So for Example 2 I would expect something like:
[
["C9500 Network Advantage","Active", "PID:C9500-24Y4C,SN:AB123456CDE", "PERPETUAL", "", "", "1"],
["C9500 Network Advantage","Standby", "PID:C9500-24Y4C,SN:AB123456CDE", "PERPETUAL", "", "", "1"],
["C9500 24Y4C DNA Advantage","Active", "PID:C9500-24Y4C,SN:AB123456CDE", "TERM", "2021-JUN-12 UTC", "2026-JUN-12 UTC", "1"],
["C9500 24Y4C DNA Advantage","Standby", "PID:C9500-24Y4C,SN:AB123456CDE", "TERM", "2021-JUN-12 UTC", "2026-JUN-12 UTC", "1"],
]

Example 1 would be similar but shorter:
[
["C9500 Network Advantage","Active", "PID:C9500-48Y4C,SN:AB123456CDE", "TERM", "2021-MAR-11 UTC", "2026-MAR-11 UTC", "1"],
["C9500 24Y4C DNA Advantage","Active", "PID:C9500-48Y4C,SN:AB123456CDE", "PERPETUAL", "", "", "1"],
]

Right now I have this.  Im trying to parse the entire output which has many sections. Im hoping if I can understand how to pull out the purchased licenses section the rest will be a bit easier as I believe this is due to my lack of understanding of how to move around in the sections, record multiline data, and potentially clear out values.
Value SMART_LIC_STATE (\S+)
# Usage Reporting
Value LAST_ACK_RCV (.+)
Value NEXT_ACK_DEADLINE (.+)
Value RPT_PUSH_INTV (.+)
Value NEXT_ACK_PUSH (.+)
Value NEXT_RPT_PUSH (.+)
Value LAST_RPT_PUSH (.+)
Value LAST_RPT_FILE (.+)
# Purchased Licenses
Value Filldown TITLE (C\d\d\d\d\s+.+\s+\(.+\))
Value List PLIC_LINES (.+)
Value DESC (.+)
Value RESV (\d+)


Start
  ^Smart Licensing Status$$
  ^=+$$
  ^\s+$$
  ^Smart Licensing is ${SMART_LIC_STATE}$$
  ^Usage\s+Reporting:$$ -> UsageReporting
  ^Purchased\s+Licenses:$$ -> PurchasedLicenses

UsageReporting
  ^\s+Last ACK received:\s+${LAST_ACK_RCV}$$
  ^\s+Next ACK deadline:\s+${NEXT_ACK_DEADLINE}$$
  ^\s+Reporting push interval:\s+${RPT_PUSH_INTV}$$
  ^\s+Next ACK push check:\s+${NEXT_ACK_PUSH}$$
  ^\s+Next report push:\s+${NEXT_RPT_PUSH}$$
  ^\s+Last report push:\s+${LAST_RPT_PUSH}$$
  ^\s+Last report file write:\s+${LAST_RPT_FILE}$$

PurchasedLicenses
  ^\s+${TITLE}:$$
#  ^\s+Description:\s+${DESC}$$
#  ^\s+Total reserved count:\s${RESV}$$
  ^${PLIC_LINES}
  ^\s+${TITLE}:$$ -> Record PurchasedLicenses


RESULT from template above:
['SMART_LIC_STATE', 'LAST_ACK_RCV', 'NEXT_ACK_DEADLINE', 'RPT_PUSH_INTV', 'NEXT_ACK_PUSH', 'NEXT_RPT_PUSH', 'LAST_RPT_PUSH', 'LAST_RPT_FILE', 'TITLE', 'PLIC_LINES', 'DESC', 'RESV']
[['ENABLED', 'Apr 10 15:30:04 2024 CEST', 'Jul 09 15:30:04 2024 CEST', '30  days', '<none>', 'May 10 15:25:06 2024 CEST', 'Apr 10 15:25:06 2024 CEST', '<none>', '', [], '', '']]


The full output of show license all as an example (again, this is model and software version specific).
!--- show license all on a C9500
Smart Licensing Status
======================

Smart Licensing is ENABLED

Export Authorization Key:
  Features Authorized:
    <none>

Utility:
  Status: DISABLED

Smart Licensing Using Policy:
  Status: ENABLED

Account Information:
  Smart Account: ACME Inc.  Blah Blah
  Virtual Account: DEFAULT

Data Privacy:
  Sending Hostname: yes
    Callhome hostname privacy: DISABLED
    Smart Licensing hostname privacy: DISABLED
  Version privacy: DISABLED

Transport:
  Type: Callhome

Miscellaneous:
  Custom Id: <empty>

Policy:
  Policy in use: Merged from multiple sources.
  Reporting ACK required: yes (CISCO default)
  Unenforced/Non-Export Perpetual Attributes:
    First report requirement (days): 365 (CISCO default)
    Reporting frequency (days): 0 (CISCO default)
    Report on change (days): 90 (CISCO default)
  Unenforced/Non-Export Subscription Attributes:
    First report requirement (days): 90 (CISCO default)
    Reporting frequency (days): 90 (CISCO default)
    Report on change (days): 90 (CISCO default)
  Enforced (Perpetual/Subscription) License Attributes:
    First report requirement (days): 0 (CISCO default)
    Reporting frequency (days): 0 (CISCO default)
    Report on change (days): 0 (CISCO default)
  Export (Perpetual/Subscription) License Attributes:
    First report requirement (days): 0 (CISCO default)
    Reporting frequency (days): 0 (CISCO default)
    Report on change (days): 0 (CISCO default)

Usage Reporting:
  Last ACK received: <none>
  Next ACK deadline: Jan 26 22:28:05 2022 New York
  Reporting push interval: 30  days
  Next ACK push check: <none>
  Next report push: Mar 13 20:58:31 2024 New York
  Last report push: <none>
  Last report file write: <none>

Trust Code Installed: <none>

License Usage
=============

network-advantage (C9500 Network Advantage):
  Description: C9500 Network Advantage
  Count: 2
  Version: 1.0
  Status: IN USE
  Export status: NOT RESTRICTED
  Feature Name: network-advantage
  Feature Description: C9500 Network Advantage
  Enforcement type: NOT ENFORCED
  License type: Perpetual

dna-advantage (C9500 48Y4C DNA Advantage):
  Description: C9500-48Y4C DNA Advantage
  Count: 2
  Version: 1.0
  Status: IN USE
  Export status: NOT RESTRICTED
  Feature Name: dna-advantage
  Feature Description: C9500-48Y4C DNA Advantage
  Enforcement type: NOT ENFORCED
  License type: Subscription

Product Information
===================
UDI: PID:C9500-48Y4C,SN:AB123456CDE

HA UDI List:
    Active:PID:C9500-48Y4C,SN:AB123456CDE
    Standby:PID:C9500-48Y4C,SN:AB123456CDE

Agent Version
=============
Smart Agent for Licensing: 5.5.29_rel/114

License Authorizations
======================
Overall status:
  Active: PID:C9500-48Y4C,SN:AB123456CDE
      Status: NOT INSTALLED
  Standby: PID:C9500-48Y4C,SN:AB123456CDE
      Status: NOT INSTALLED

Purchased Licenses:
  C9500 Network Advantage (C9500 Network Advantage):
    Description: C9500 Network Advantage
    Total reserved count: 2
    Term information:
      Active: PID:C9500-48Y4C,SN:AB123456CDE
        License type: PERPETUAL
          Term Count: 1
      Standby: PID:C9500-48Y4C,SN:AB123456CDE
        License type: PERPETUAL
          Term Count: 1
  C9500 48Y4C DNA Advantage (C9500 48Y4C DNA Advantage):
    Description: C9500 48Y4C DNA Advantage
    Total reserved count: 2
    Term information:
      Active: PID:C9500-48Y4C,SN:AB123456CDE
        License type: TERM
          Start Date: 2021-DEC-11 UTC
          End Date: 2026-DEC-11 UTC
          Term Count: 1
      Standby: PID:C9500-48Y4C,SN:AB123456CDE
        License type: TERM
          Start Date: 2021-DEC-11 UTC
          End Date: 2026-DEC-11 UTC
          Term Count: 1

Derived Licenses:
  Entitlement Tag: regid.2019-03.com.cisco.advantagek9-Nyquist-C9500,1.0_f1563778-2e03-4a4c-bec5-5fjjc525a12c

Usage Report Summary:
=====================
Total: 23,  Purged: 0
Total Acknowledged Received: 0,  Waiting for Ack: 0
Available to Report: 23  Collecting Data: 2  

